# Irreducible representations of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I want to prove that $S_n$ has an irreducible representation of dimension $n-1$.
Intuitively, I know that the $\forall n$, the trivial representation is irreducible, and there should be some complimentary subspace which is irreducible. However, I am new to representation theory, and I am unable to formalize the proof. Any hints and ideas on how to go about this are welcome.

Comment: It might help to know which results you already have seen. Have you seen any nice criteria that guarantee irreducibility?

Comment: Anyway, the idea of finding a complement to the trivial representation would require that to already be inside another representation. Do you know the permutation representation?

Comment: Yes, Tobias. I know the permutation representation. Its dimension is also 1, but I can't relate it to this problem.

Comment: No, the permutation representation does not have dimension $1$. It has dimension $n$.

Comment: This question has been asked a couple of times on math.SE and also on mathoverflow. In the marked duplicate Martin Sleziak has given an elementary proof that the standard representation $\{(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) : x_1 + \dotsc + x_n = 0\}$ of $S_n$ is irreducible. (Over any field of characteristic zero.)